# Commas in Javascript if statements?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for this maybe stupid question, but how can I use commas in `if` statements?
This is the normal part:

```
  $("a[rel*=overlay]").overlay({
    fixed: false,
    closeOnClick: false,
      onBeforeLoad: function() {
        var wrap = this.getOverlay().find("#contentWrap");
        var eID = this.getTrigger().attr("id").replace(/.$/g, '');
        var hiURL = document.location.href;
        var eURL = this.getTrigger().attr("href");
        var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
        wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        window.location.hash = (eID);
      },
  onClose: function() {
        window.something(something);
  }
  });
```

I need:

```
  $("a[rel*=overlay]").overlay({
    fixed: false,
    closeOnClick: false,
      onBeforeLoad: function() {
        var wrap = this.getOverlay().find("#contentWrap");
        var eID = this.getTrigger().attr("id").replace(/.$/g, '');
        var hiURL = document.location.href;
        var eURL = this.getTrigger().attr("href");
        var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
        wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        if (Modernizr.history) {
          window.history.replaceState(currentPage, document.title, eURL);
          },
            onClose: function() {
              window.history.replaceState(currentPage, document.title, "dort");
        } else {
        window.location.hash = (eID);
        }
      }
  });
```

But the `"},"` shows an error in dreamweaver.

Comment: we need the rest of the code above this... you are missing an important part here.

Comment: Your original code snippet would be completely broken on its own. What code is around that?

Comment: your "normal" part doesn't work...

Comment: Where is `onClose` supposed to be associated to? `window`? You syntax is totally off. You better should explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: sorry, updated and you can see now the whole code

Comment: I have updated my answer with the solution, I hope you have solved it by now, but if not good luck!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I have replaced my orig answer with this one, thus making most of the comments invalid.  At the time I posted the author had not given enough info to solve the problem, and I had a typo in my pseudo answer.

You where close to getting it correct, just missing one bracket...

```
  $("a[rel*=overlay]").overlay({
    fixed: false,
    closeOnClick: false,
      onBeforeLoad: function() {
        var wrap = this.getOverlay().find("#contentWrap");
        var eID = this.getTrigger().attr("id").replace(/.$/g, '');
        var hiURL = document.location.href;
        var eURL = this.getTrigger().attr("href");
        var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
        wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        if (Modernizr.history) {
          window.history.replaceState(currentPage, document.title, eURL);
        } // <-- Missing this one
      },
      onClose: function() {
          window.history.replaceState(currentPage, document.title, "dort");
        } else {
          window.location.hash = (eID);
        }
      }
  });
```

Comment: `onClose: function() {` looks very wrong if it is not in the context of an object literal. And there is still a bracket to much.... definitely not runnable! I seriously wonder who upvoted this...

Comment: It probably would pass a syntax check as a label, but yea, one bracket to many...

Comment: @MooGoo: Yes `onClose:` would pass, but not the anonymous function declaration: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (*

Comment: Eeek yes, it would have to be wrapped in parenthesis to pass as a valid expression. JS syntax still tricks me sometimes.

Comment: Ok, looks like that doesnt work do say if history than make this on onBeforeLoad and this onClose and if no history than make a hash. I have now to "if history querys". One for close and one for onbeforload and that works. Tought i can save one if query.